# text adventure - how to add items to 'inventory' struct/class without defining each in advance?

Tags: c++, adventure

So far this is the most awkward thing I've come about. I have it set for integers to mark how many potions, keys, a player has, but I'm not sure exactly how I can get random items, like rocks, CPU (in the case of Dunnet), stick, shovel, etc.

I don't want to have to figure out every item in the game and assign it a variable. There has to be an easier way. I thought of using two arrays, one a string and one an int, to do the job - but this wont work for a variety of reasons one being I can't do string stringname[10], I see problems associating the two, and... the list goes on, I'm sure it just wont work that way.

Everything else is a class btw, I don't like using structs (but this is going to be used throughout the code, and accessed everywhere), so far my code is:

```
struct Inventory{
    int Keys;
    int Potions;
    int getinventory() const { return Keys, Potions; }
    void addkey(int amt){ Keys += amt; }
    void addpotion(int amt){ Potions += amt; }
    void usepotion(){Potions -= 1;}
    void usekey()
    {
        if (Keys >> 0)
        {
            Keys -= 1;
        }
        else if (Keys << 1)
        {
            cout << "You do not have a key!" << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

I'm definitely still working on the getinventory(), because well, I'm not sure what I'm doing with this code, or even if I'm using it. is the only way I'm going to get this to work, to define EACH variable as I create it in the game and add it in?

I was going to handle weapons and monsters this way... but it just sucks not having a dynamic system for an inventory. I'd like to focus on parsing user input and not have to go back into the header where my main classes are consistently... plus I haven't even fully written the story yet, so I don't know whats happening...

Comment: i think you mean if key > 0 not >> 0

Comment: Your `getInventory()` function is bogus: `return Keys, Potions;` only returns `Potions`. See [*comma operator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

Answer (score 1):

The way this is addressed in LPMuds (and similar) is to create a generic object template.  The generic template would have things like a short description, long description, define weight, value, etc.

Specific object types then inherit this class.  For example, a potion is an object with all of those attributes but it also has additional actions (functions) that can be taken and possibly different attributes...  Taste and color, for example.

Weapons can inherit from that general class, defining things like damage and hit percentage as a generalized notion.  A sword can then inherit this weapon (that inherits the generic object) and can be further refined.

In this way, you simply need your inventory to be able to handle a generic object.  The objects themselves may define additional attributes and actions.  This also means that you don't need to predefine every single object as its own unique variable.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a structure like this:

```
struct InventoryItem
{
  enum { Key, Potion, Rock, Stick, Shovel } type_;
  unsigned int num_;
}
```

and then have `Inventory` contain something like a `std::vector` of InventoryItem.

Comment: `InventoryItem` looks very much like a pair. Whenever you have a list of pairs, think about `std::map` -- I reckon that's what fits the best here :)